# ACF Field Key Issues with REST API After a Plugin Update

Tags: wordpress

We're encountering recurring issues with Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) in our backend-driven WordPress application. After a recent version upgrade, the ACF-to-REST plugin broke, which prompted me to explore ACF's built-in endpoint exposure.

I've successfully set up ACF's own endpoint, but I'm facing a problem with repeater fields. When accessing the endpoint, the fields are assigned random keys, making it difficult to work with the data as expected. Here's a screenshot below illustrating the issue.

- Has anyone else experienced similar issues with ACF's built-in
  endpoint and repeater fields after an upgrade?

  2.Are there any known solutions or workarounds for maintaining stable field keys when using ACF's built-in endpoint?

  3. Alternatively, should we consider exploring other solutions? I appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve
     this problem and ensure the sustainability of our backend-driven
     application with ACF.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use a custom REST API endpoint that will return exactly what you want

Here is the short example you can start with:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'acfroute/v1', '/resource/', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'acf_endpoint',
  ) );
} );

function acf_endpoint( $data ) {
  $posts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
  ) );

  foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    // Get ACF fields here as you need 
  }

  return $formatted_data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, sorry to ask more of you but how should I proceed to fetch the ACF fields?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply

Here is example how can you do that

function acf_endpoint( $data ) {
  $posts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
  ) );

  $formatted_data = [];

  foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    
    $post_data = [
      'ID' => $post->ID,
      'title' => $post->post_title,
      'content' => $post->post_content,
    ];

    $acf_fields = get_fields($post->ID);

    $post_data['acf'] = $acf_fields;

    $formatted_data[] = $post_data;
  }

  return $formatted_data;
}

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was having duplicate field groups. When I removed one the problem disappeared.